# How do I install Debian 9?

Tags: debian, system-installation

I tried to install Debian 9 with a bootable USB. But almost at the end of the installation I encountered an error saying,
"Debootstrap error. 
Failed to determine the codename for the release". 
It occurred during the "Install the system" step. And by the way I didn't choose any mirror because I was getting an error something like, this mirror isn't found or suitable for every mirror I choose.

Comment: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=110803 ``mount /dev/sdc1 /cdrom``

Comment: Please add the command you used to your question, as well as the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the installer doesn't know to identify that it is being installed via usb.So you have to manually mount the usb to /cdrom.You can do this by hitting **alt-f2** and then **mount /dev/sdc1 /cdrom** then press **alt-f1** to get back to the install.

The device for the usb drive may vary. For myexample it was /dev/sdc1.